# Find start/stop location of sharp cumulative events

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Here is an example set of data:

EDIT: Included some more data.

```
x = [0, 5, 6,15, 20, 40, 73,
     100,101,102,103,104,105,106,108,111,115,
     116,117,118,119,120,123,124,125,126,127,
     128,129,130,131, 150,161,170, 183, 194,
     210, 234, 257, 271,272,273,274, 275,276,
     277,278,279,280,281,282,283,284,285,287,
     288,291,292,293,294,295,296,297,298,300,301,
     302,303,304,305,306,307,308,309,310,311,
     340, 351, 358, 360, 380, 390, 400,401,
     402,403, 404, 405, 408, 409, 413, 420,
     425,426,427,428,429,430,431,432,433,434,435,
     436, 440, 450, 455]

y = np.arange(1, len(x)+1)
```

[image]

Here is what the data visually looks like and has the potentially for each sharp increase to be longer. The last sharp increase also has a pause, but I would like it to still be considered one set of data. Black dots are the gradient.

I am attempting to find the the start/end x-values for each sharp increase in cumulative counts. So the output should be an array of indexes, like what Riley has done.

A vectorized method would be ideal to help with any time constraints to quickly go through data. Here is rough outline of what has been done so far within a pandas dataframe.

- Shift the "x-data" and take a difference
- See if sequential differences are below a threshold to create logic array
- Do rolling sum on logic array with so Trues will continue add to count
- Find when rolling sum exceeds another threshold
- Compare with previous value to ensure it is increase/decreasing for start/stop times
- Add times to index list

It seems a little finicky on some of the rolling averages and isn't as quick as I would like. Multiplying some of these large arrays with logic arrays seems to take a good amount of time.

EDIT: Here is the code Riley has provided and offers an excellent start. It is also only a couple lines a code, versus my method above was almost 50 or so.

```
rate_threshold = 0.25 
min_consecutive = 8 
above_rate = np.gradient(y,x) >= rate_threshold
sequence_diff = np.diff(np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(above_rate, window_shape=min_consecutive).all(axis=1).astype(int))
intervals = np.hstack([np.argwhere(sequence_diff==1) + 1, np.argwhere(sequence_diff==-1) + min_consecutive-1])
```

The new issue comes from the final sharp increase of data. Two sets of start/end points are returned, where the desired would just be one.

My initial thought is to include some kind of average routine with the sliding window to account for these drops in the gradient so the end is so hard set.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your desired output would look like, so let's start with this, verify it does it what you want it to, then go from there

```
rate_threshold = 1
min_consecutive = 5

above_rate = np.diff(y)/np.diff(x) >= rate_threshold
sequence_diff = np.diff(sliding_window_view(above_rate, window_shape=min_consecutive).all(axis=1).astype(int))
intervals = np.hstack([np.argwhere(sequence_diff==1) + 1, np.argwhere(sequence_diff==-1) + min_consecutive-1])
```

`intervals` is a 2d numpy array of indices whose 2 columns are first index, and last index in a sequence (of length `min_consecutive`) of rates above the threshold

```
array([[ 7, 12],
       [16, 20],
       [22, 29],
       [39, 52],
       [56, 62],
       [64, 74]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying the desired output! This example dataset would have two collections of start/stop times for the two sharp increases of counts. 

I'm wondering if the above_rate variable should be np.gradient()?

Comment: Not sure about `np.gradient` - maybe?  Set rate_threshold = 0.25 in the above and see if it gets your answer?

Comment: That worked for the most part and came up with another issue, I've updated the question with the relevant information.

Comment: "The last sharp increase also has a pause, but I would like it to still be considered one set of data."  How do you propose to decide what is a small enough pause, and what is not?

Comment: Excellent question. I’m thinking another variable set by a user. If the pause lasts less than “user set amount of time” it is still one set of data. Otherwise continue on and find next set of data. 

I know this could be done in a loop, but still hoping to avoid that for time. Especially if the data is millions of points.